# How to fix this in MTASA

Tags: lua, mta

If a player hits this marker, every player on the same server will start working. What I want to do is to make it work only for the player who hits the marker. How to fix this?

getJobMarker = createMarker(872.03754, -29.07278, 62.3000, "cylinder", 1.0, 0, 255, 255, 255, getRootElement())
ped = createPed(159, 872.92389, -27.08743, 63.94565, 160)
setPedFrozen(ped, true)
blip = createBlipAttachedTo(getJobMarker, 56)

function hitMarkerWindow()
window = guiCreateWindow(0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.30, "wood job", true)
memo = guiCreateMemo(0.10, 0.20, 0.80, 0.4, "this is wood cutting job", true, window)
accept = guiCreateButton(0.10, 0.75, 0.22, 0.14, "Accept Job", true, window)
leave = guiCreateButton(0.35, 0.75, 0.22, 0.14, "Leave Job", true, window)
close = guiCreateButton(0.60, 0.75, 0.22, 0.14, "Close", true, window)
showCursor(true)
guiMemoSetReadOnly(memo, true)
end

addEventHandler("onClientMarkerHit", getJobMarker, hitMarkerWindow)

function clientClick()
if source == close then
guiSetVisible(window, false)
showCursor(false)
triggerServerEvent("cancelButton", resourceRoot, localPlayer)
elseif source == accept then
guiSetVisible(window, false)
showCursor(false)
triggerServerEvent("acceptWoodJob", resourceRoot, localPlayer)
elseif source == leave then
guiSetVisible(window, false)
showCursor(false)
triggerServerEvent("leaveJob", resourceRoot, localPlayer)

```
end
```

end

addEventHandler("onClientGUIClick", root,  clientClick)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.